# Asterisk interacting with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asterisk, asteriskami

I'm very new to Asterisk, but I need to build an app that would be able to do 3 things in interaction with it.

1. Request and receive call history for a specific time period.
2. Initiate an outgoing call to a specified number upon submitting a custom form.
3. Act as a router for Asterisk: upoin an incomming call Asterisk sends the call number to the app and receives the internal CallerID the call needs to be routed to. If that number is unavailable, the call is routed to the group.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please indicate what research you have done and what code you have written and are having issues with.  Asterisk and Rails can do what you are asking here, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your question, I would say your language of choice is Ruby. As such, I suggest that you take a look at Adhearsion (http://www.adhearsion.com/), which should provide you with ample information, as to how to integrate Asterisk with Ruby.

Nir S